# jQuery select various information from different <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with the following HTML:

```
<tr class="oddrow">
    <td>row1</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%">-1<br>+1</td>
                        <td width="50%">WSH: -110<br>SAC: -110</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%">202.5</td>
                        <td width="50%">o: -110<br>u: -110</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">WSH: 0<br>SAC: 0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="evenrow">
    <td>row2</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%">-1<br>+1</td>
                        <td width="50%">WSH: -110<br>SAC: -110</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%">202.5</td>
                        <td width="50%">o: -110<br>u: -110</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">WSH: 0<br>SAC: 0</td>
    <!-- The above line is the one I need. --!>
</tr>
```

There are 2 such rows (`row1` and `row2`), alternating as an `oddrow` then `evenrow`. I have the entire HTML as a string in my JavaScript/jQuery code. I also have the information of the two three-letter abbreviations: in this example, `WSH` and `SAC`. What I need is the third `<td style="text-align:center;">` of the `row2` row. I should point out that there are several tables of `row1` and `row2` on the page, so I need a general selector. What I have been doing is just grabbing all the data in all the rows then parsing it from there, but the inconsistency of the data is making that more difficult. Is there a quick and dirty jQuery that will point me to the data I need?

I was thinking something like `$("tr td:contains(" + abbrev + ") td:contains('row2')").text();`, but that doesn't get it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you have the HTML in your script, why not clean it up with some classes and target those? Selecting by style attribute sounds like a recipe for failure down the road. Styles shouldn't be inline anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy in your selector is wrong, `td`s with the abbreviation are not an ancestor to the `td`s with the text of "row2"

You also need to ensure you have apostrophes around your `abbrev` variable.

Can you try:

```
$("tr td:contains('row2') td:contains('" + abbrev + "')").text()
```

Any chance you can add semantic classes instead? These sorts of selectors are gnarly to maintain.

Comment: yeah it is nasty but it's just HTML i pulled down from a webpage. is there an efficient way to parse through and add classes?

Comment: thanks, i'll try this out...i would think this would grab a list of rows (or at least the first row) because more than one <tr> has the abbrev in it, not just that third one. maybe i can use .last()?

Comment: here's a fiddle, i can't get it to work quite right... http://jsfiddle.net/y2TL8/